# Get positive elements adjacent to particular row

Tags: mysql, filter

I have a table and I would like to extract all values in column `diff2` which are equal to 1 and are adjacent to another value 1 starting from row where `SERIES = 'SERIE A' and rn='1'`. Is there a way to select this subtable without using a loop?

[image: Original data]

Desired result:

[image: Final table]

Comment: A combination of `LEAD()` and `LAG()` functions should give you what you want

Comment: Is that a typo in your problem description?  It says starting from rn = 1 but your image shows a dataset ordered by rn2

Comment: @RobEyre there is a column named rn and a column named rn2, dividing serie A and serie B. My origin is `rn='1'`, so there is no typo

Comment: Please never present textual input data as an image.  Also present text as copy-pasted text to remove any ambiguity in the data.  For highest quality and fastest responses from volunteer contributors, please offer a MySQL sandbox demo link so that they can play with your exact data/schema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be ordering your results by series ascending and rn descending.  You can use the `LAG()` and `LEAD()` functions with a subquery to achieve your desired result set:

```
select date, series, rn, rn2, diff2 from (
    select
        date,
        series,
        rn,
        rn2,
        diff2,
        lag(diff2) over (order by series, rn desc) as preceding,
        lead(diff2) over (order by series, rn desc) as following
    from mytable
) sub
where sub.diff2 = 1
and (sub.preceding = 1 or sub.following = 1)
order by series, rn desc
```

Results:

```
+------------+---------+----+-----+-------+
| date       | series  | rn | rn2 | diff2 |
+------------+---------+----+-----+-------+
| 2023-09-22 | SERIE A |  3 |  17 |     1 |
| 2023-09-22 | SERIE A |  2 |  18 |     1 |
| 2023-09-22 | SERIE A |  1 |  19 |     1 |
| 2023-09-22 | SERIE B | 13 |  20 |     1 |
+------------+---------+----+-----+-------+
```

If, however, your intention is to return all rows with diff2 that are in a contiguous block with the selected one, then you could achieve this with a self join.

For the rows in the top half of the table (before the selected row), we look for any intervening row (between the current row and the selected row) that has diff2 = 0.  If we find one, then we exclude the current row.

Similarly for the rows in the bottom half of the table (after the selected row), we look for any intervening row (between the current row and the selected row) that has diff2 = 0.  If we find one, then we exclude the current row.

```
select
    t.date, t.series, t.rn, t.rn2, t.diff2
from mytable t
left join mytable intervening ON
    (
        (
            (t.series < "SERIE A" OR t.series = "SERIE A" AND t.rn > 1)
            and (intervening.series < "SERIE A" OR intervening.series = "SERIE A" AND intervening.rn > 1)
            and (intervening.series > t.series OR intervening.series = t.series AND intervening.rn < t.rn)

        ) OR
        (
            (t.series > "SERIE A" OR t.series = "SERIE A" AND t.rn < 1)
            and (intervening.series > "SERIE A" OR intervening.series = "SERIE A" AND intervening.rn < 1)
            and (intervening.series < t.series OR intervening.series = t.series AND intervening.rn > t.rn)
        )
    )
    and intervening.diff2 = 0

where t.diff2 = 1
and intervening.diff2 is null
order by t.series, t.rn desc
```

This gives the desired result:

```
+------------+---------+----+-----+-------+
| date       | series  | rn | rn2 | diff2 |
+------------+---------+----+-----+-------+
| 2023-09-22 | SERIE A |  3 |  17 |     1 |
| 2023-09-22 | SERIE A |  2 |  18 |     1 |
| 2023-09-22 | SERIE A |  1 |  19 |     1 |
| 2023-09-22 | SERIE B | 13 |  20 |     1 |
+------------+---------+----+-----+-------+
```

Comment: Your solution worked perfectly, but my example was not good enough. Like I said, I want only `diff2=1` if its adjacent to my `rn=19`. If there are adjacent ones, but not adjacent to `rn=19`, I want to filter those. I have edited my data to be more specific.

Comment: @OsvaldoAssunção thanks for the clarification - I have amended my answer accordingly with an alternative approach which I think does what you need